# Segmentation fault ../string/strstr.c: No such file or directory

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, xdebug-3

I'm getting a segmentation fault running a script using a custom PHP 8.1.9 compiled with phpbrew tool.

I've executed gdb and trying to debug the segmentation fault but I'm not sure of the next step I should take.

Here's the result

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs$ gdb -args /opt/phpbrew/php/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/bin/php -c .user.ini -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento command:feed:generate default
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /opt/phpbrew/php/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/bin/php...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /opt/phpbrew/php/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/bin/php -c .user.ini -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento command:feed:generate default
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_enable' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_enable (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_host' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_host (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_port' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_port (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
Lock Acquired
Processing...
Fetchings product in included categories
Fetching products in excluded categories
Fetching products data

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff737dfdb in __strstr_sse2 (haystack=0x7fffeda2c8a0 "Vendor\\Module\\Helper\\Data", needle=0x7ffff4692b39 "@anonymous") at ../string/strstr.c:84
84      ../string/strstr.c: No such file or directory.
```

The output of `where`

```
#0  0x00007ffff737dfdb in __strstr_sse2 (haystack=0x7fffeea2de88 "Vendor\\Module\\Helper\\Data", needle=0x7ffff4692b39 "@anonymous") at ../string/strstr.c:84
#1  0x00007ffff466438e in xdebug_build_fname (tmp=tmp@entry=0x7fffe9db2b20, edata=edata@entry=0x7fffea46f120) at /opt/phpbrew/build/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/ext/xdebug/src/base/base.c:218
#2  0x00007ffff46647ca in xdebug_add_stack_frame (zdata=<optimized out>, zdata@entry=0x7fffea46f070, op_array=op_array@entry=0x7fffeb955ae0, type=type@entry=1)
    at /opt/phpbrew/build/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/ext/xdebug/src/base/base.c:615
#3  0x00007ffff4664f88 in xdebug_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fffea46f120) at /opt/phpbrew/build/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/ext/xdebug/src/base/base.c:721
#4  0x0000555555b2f24d in ZEND_DO_FCALL_SPEC_RETVAL_USED_HANDLER () at /opt/phpbrew/build/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:1837
#5  execute_ex (ex=0x7fffeea2de88) at /opt/phpbrew/build/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:55788
#6  0x00007ffff4665092 in xdebug_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fffea46f070) at /opt/phpbrew/build/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/ext/xdebug/src/base/base.c:779
#7  0x0000555555b2f24d in ZEND_DO_FCALL_SPEC_RETVAL_USED_HANDLER () at /opt/phpbrew/build/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:1837
#8  execute_ex (ex=0x7fffeea2de88) at /opt/phpbrew/build/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:55788
#9  0x00007ffff4665092 in xdebug_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fffea46efc0) at /opt/phpbrew/build/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/ext/xdebug/src/base/base.c:779
#10 0x0000555555b2f24d in ZEND_DO_FCALL_SPEC_RETVAL_USED_HANDLER () at /opt/phpbrew/build/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:1837
#11 execute_ex (ex=0x7fffeea2de88) at /opt/phpbrew/build/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:55788
#12 0x00007ffff4665092 in xdebug_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7fffea46ef10) at /opt/phpbrew/build/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/ext/xdebug/src/base/base.c:779
#13 0x0000555555b2f24d in ZEND_DO_FCALL_SPEC_RETVAL_USED_HANDLER () at /opt/phpbrew/build/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:1837
#14 execute_ex (ex=0x7fffeea2de88) at /opt/phpbrew/build/phpbrew8_1_9_fdev/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:55788
#15 0x00007ffff4665092 in xdebug_execute_ex
```

These lines keep repeating endlessly for more than a few minutes when I type c to continue without paging.

Comment: Please update your question with the the output of GDB `where` command (after you've got `SIGSEGV`).

Comment: It looks like a loop of the same output

Comment: I found the issue by step debugging the code, it was a recursive function which would never exit.

Comment: "recursive function which would never exit" -- so you have stack overflow -- as I suspected. It's a bug in PHP, but that's all I can say. You said "custom PHP" -- perhaps the customization introduced the bug?

Comment: Perhaps custom was the wrong word. I meant compiled using a tool called phpbrew with a specific set of extensions. I can't be sure if it was a bug introduced by phpbrew though.